# jQuery code inside GSP page

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, gsp

In my gsp page there is a need to include some jQuery code. My page does not have head and title it starts from div tag. How to include jQuery script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would do in the `head`. It's unnecessary to do that strictly in the `head`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
   // we will add our javascript code here                                     
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check [Jquery Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery) for grails.